# substr on pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr

I am trying to write a small pl/sql script and need some help.
first, I have 2 tables called project1 , project2. both tables have a column called cust_code.

cust_code values are varchar2 type. values always begin with 1. (number 1, decimal point) and 8 digits. for example 1.10002332

when I import data into project1 table, if the last digit is 0, for example 1.22321630, the last zero is dropped and then theres only seven digits beyond the decimal point. in that case it will be 1.2232163

the script I want to write  will check whether there are only 7 digits beyond the decimal point and will insert that record into the project2 table.
this is what I came up with

```
DECLARE

       CURSOR dif IS
            SELECT CUST_CODE, CUST_ID, CONTRACT_NUM, MSISDN 
            FROM project1
            WHERE CUST_CODE IN (SELECT CUST_CODE FROM CUST_ALL);

BEGIN

        FOR a in dif LOOP

            IF SUBSTR(a.CUST_CODE, 10)=null
            THEN
            INSERT INTO project2 (cust_code)
            VALUES(a.CUST_CODE);           
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        commit;

END;
```

the script runs with no errors but nothing happens. on the substr function, when I chose different value than NULL, then it works.  I cant figure out how to check if the 8th digit is missing.

Assaf.

Comment: In plsql `something=null` is always false, you need `something IS null`

Comment: @A.B.Cade: I think it's pretty much any SQL, not just PL/SQL. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't work because of the line:

```
IF SUBSTR(a.CUST_CODE, 10)=null
```

In plsql `<something> = null` will always be FALSE.
You should write:

```
IF SUBSTR(a.CUST_CODE, 10) IS null
```

But actually you don't really nead plsql, you can do it with one sql command:

```
INSERT INTO project2 (cust_code)
SELECT CUST_CODE, CUST_ID, CONTRACT_NUM, MSISDN 
            FROM project1
            WHERE CUST_CODE IN (SELECT CUST_CODE FROM CUST_ALL)
              AND SUBSTR(a.CUST_CODE, 10) IS null;
```

Comment: thank you! the IS null did make the difference.
i am tryin to learn pl/sql and this specific little script is only the beginning of a slightly bigger one that will make a couple of things at work easier. thanks again (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your condition:

```
IF LENGTH(a.CUST_CODE) = 10 AND SUBSTR(a.CUST_CODE,-1,10) = '0'
```

(check if length is 10 and also last character is 0)

Comment: thank you very much. didnt know the LENGTH function which is very useful (: